# How to convert DataFrame from HTML to SQL using Pandas and use it for a Search field in Flask?

Tags: python, pandas, flask, beautifulsoup

Having gather all results from **scraping** a website using BeautifulSoup and have generated an HTML file with all of the lists that were fulfilled using this result´s, I now need to set a way to search for the items in a Flask website page.

My first idea was to use SQL but I need to convert my data to SQL with Panda and have no idea on how to do it, even after looking some tutorials.

On the flask side I´m using the file from static folder since it´s been generated by Panda in BeautifulSoup:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask('__name__',static_url_path='')
@app.route('/index/')
def root():
    return app.send_static_file('jobs.html')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and on Beautiful Soup side I have the following:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Date":date_list,"Job":Job_name_list,"Company":company_list,"Location":location_list,"Description":description_list,"Link":links_list})
Export = data.to_html (r'C:....\jobs.html')
```

Everything is working fine on using the html and displaying it on the website so far, just need your input on how can I create a search field in Flask and convert it to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

With SQLAlchemy, you can write a DataFrame to a SQL table with [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). Since you're using Flask, use [`flask_sqlalchemy`](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) for better integration:

With `flask_sqlalchemy`, you can get the `engine` by accessing it through the `db` object.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Date":date_list,"Job":Job_name_list,"Company":company_list,"Location":location_list,"Description":description_list,"Link":links_list})

data.to_sql(name='your_model', con=db.engine, index=False)
```